# null pointer exception on addmarker and markeroptions on googleMap

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I get nullpointerException when trying to load google map on our app as below.also The java class extends from `AppCompatActivty`and inside `intialiseMap()` we try to `getMap()`

```
D/Profileactivity: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference
```

And here is where we get the exception,inside placeMarker method

```
public void placeMarker(LatLongDetails user_latlongobj2,
                        final Context contextPlace) {
    try {
        if (googlemap == null) {
            intialiseMap();
            animatecamera(user_latlongobj);
        }
        if (LoginDetails.Address.length() < 1) {
            LoginDetails.Address = "Getting your location .....";
        }
        //googlemap.clear();
        marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(user_latlongobj2.user_latitude,
                        user_latlongobj2.user_longitude)).title(
                LoginDetails.Address);

        System.out.println("This is the Address" + LoginDetails.Address);

        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker));

        if (googlemap != null) {

            googlemap.addMarker(marker).showInfoWindow();
        }else {
            intialiseMap();
            googlemap.addMarker(marker).showInfoWindow();
        }
        System.out.println("PLACING MARKER" + LoginDetails.Address);
        if (marker == null || contextPlace == null) {
            Intent in =new Intent(this,ProfileActivity1.class);
            in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(in);
        }
        else
            fixmarker(marker, contextPlace);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        fixmarker(marker, contextPlace);
        Log.d("Profileactivity", "" + e);
    }

}
```

This is how we initialise Map

```
private void intialiseMap() {

try {
if (dialog == null)
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ProfileActivity1.this, "",
            getString(R.string.getting_location), true, true);
}catch(Exception e) {
Log.e("eybaba",""+e);
}
    try {
        if (googlemap == null) {
            googlemap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment)).getMap();
            googlemap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfowindow(context));
            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googlemap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.string.maps_create_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd guess that `intialiseMap();` isn't working or returns a new map and the call thus should be `googlemap = intialiseMap();`. Basically the error message tells you what's wrong: `NullPointerException`.

Comment: The first warning shows that `user_longitude` in class `LatLongDetails` is a class variable that you're accessing via an instance `user_latlongobj2.user_longitude`, but has a `static` modifier. You can simply remove `static`.

Comment: @Thomas google= intialiseMap(); gives incompatible types error

Comment: `else {
            intialiseMap();
            googlemap.addMarker(marker).showInfoWindow();
        }` <-- this piece of code is executed, when `googlemap` is `null`. Referring to @Thomas comment, you need to initialize it in *some* way.

Comment: @QBrute I added this line just before asking the question here to check if  this willl solve the nullpointer exception

Comment: @QBrute removing stativ in class LatLongDetailes solve that.can u help to figure out null pointer exception.How can I intialise googleMap?google= intialiseMap(); gives incompatible types error

Comment: @HadiSamadbin Please post how you implemented `initialiseMap()`.

Comment: @QBrute just added

Comment: You should never just catch and exception and do nothing. If `intialiseMap()` fails to initialize `googlemap` you might not notice it. Btw, of course `google= intialiseMap();` will fail if `intialiseMap()` returns `void` (that's why I said I was guessing - you didn't show code then) and `google=...` would _probably_ not work anyways since the variable's name is `googlemap`.

Comment: @Thomas so what I need to to do Thomas?

Comment: Log the exceptions, check the logs and if you see a problem that you can't solve yourself ask about it. If there are no exceptions and `googlemap` still is null then debug your `initialiseMap()`.

Comment: @Thomas tnx for ur help I loged the exception found the problem and seaching for the answer ,find it and the map is now loading

Comment: @Thomas Pls write you answer as you mentioned the problem is in intialiseMap com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMap()' on a null object reference

Comment: These two Links Solved the problem 1.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116762/google-map-returning-nullpointerexception-google-maps-android-v2  2.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090867/getchildfragmentmanager-cannot-be-resolved-or-cannot-be-referenced

Comment: I'm glad it worked but besides giving tips on logging I didn't contribute much that's worth an answer :)

Comment: @Thomas But your tips plus log exception and two stackover flow links can help many others...would u pls write an answer? if possible pls mention the two links and the exception for others in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested an answer to summarize the solution and the process of finding it:

1) The `NullPointerException` and the according message indicate the problem is in the else-branch of this block:

```
    if (googlemap != null) {
        googlemap.addMarker(marker).showInfoWindow();
    }else {
        intialiseMap();
        googlemap.addMarker(marker).showInfoWindow();
    }
```

Here, `intialiseMap();` seems to fail to initialize the map.

2) In `intialiseMap()` there's a try-catch-block where `googlemap` should be initialized if null. However, the `catch`-block is empty and thus any exception when trying the initialization gets lost.

*Note for future readers:* if you catch an exception you should always, always, always handle it in some way. One of the simples ways to at least do something is to log it.

Of course there are situations where you just want to ignore a *specific* exception but in that case you should really know the consequences (what happens when that exception is thrown, why is it thrown etc.) and you always should *document* that you're ignoring that exception on purpose, e.g. with a short comment in your code.

3) After logging the caught exceptions the OP realized that initialization of `googlemap` failed and thus was able to further track the problem.

He then searched for answers and solutions and came up with the following two threads which helped him solve his problem:

- [Google Map returning nullpointerexception Google Maps Android V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116762/google-map-returning-nullpointerexception-google-maps-android-v2)
- [getChildFragmentManager () cannot be resolved or cannot be referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090867/getchildfragmentmanager-cannot-be-resolved-or-cannot-be-referenced)