# com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate on a null object reference

Tags: android

this is exactly the tittle "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.animateCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)' on a null object reference", after press search, suddenly to main activity

logcat error

```
E/Response:: [{"lat":"-7.584844","lng":"110.825068","id":"11","nama":"SMK 3 NEGERI SURAKARTA"}]
09-02 20:02:09.557 16955-16955/com.skripsi.axioo.percobaan5 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.skripsi.axioo.percobaan5, PID: 16955
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.animateCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)' on a null object reference
        at com.skripsi.axioo.percobaan5.MapsActivity$3.onResponse(MapsActivity.java:304)
        at com.skripsi.axioo.percobaan5.MapsActivity$3.onResponse(MapsActivity.java:276)
```

source code

```
    dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    dialog.show();

    String url = "https://arizalway.000webhostapp.com/api/lokasi.php?nama="+ambilcari;
    url = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
    System.out.println(url);




    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {


        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("Response: ", response);

            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);

                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(latLng));
                    lati = Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LAT));
                    longi = Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LNG));
                    if (ambilcari.equals("")) {


                        center = new LatLng(-7.568737, 110.827062);
                        cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(center).zoom(15).build();
                        gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                        getLokasi();

                    } else {
                        center = new LatLng(lati, longi);
                        cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(center).zoom(20).build();
                        gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


                        getLokasi();
                    }
                }
```

try it to search first solution but mostly the problem is not like this, this litte help for me, by adding supportfragment
[Google Map returning nullpointerexception Google Maps Android V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116762/google-map-returning-nullpointerexception-google-maps-android-v2), anyone can tell me where the most critical error except from logcat, 
this is full code https://pastebin.com/uYPbrAun

Comment: how are you getting gMap? post that line too

Comment: i dont get it, if u dont mind, u can check  link pastebin, iam very sorry

Comment: you have declare GoogleMap gMap but did not intialize it any where in code. you need to intialize that. thats why it throwing null pointer exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you `gMap` is null. you did not initialized it. intialized it in onMapReadyMethod() as

`......`

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        gMap = googleMap; //add this here
        .........
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have two GoogleMaps objects: **gMap** ang **mMap**. The one you are correctly getting and initializing is mMap but later on you're using gMap to place markers and update camera which don't exists and that's why you get the NPE.

Choose one of them and delete the other

Comment: first not deleting, experiment, by adding mMap, thank to you that i notice they different between gMap and mMap, really2 thank you

Answer (score 0):

@faiizii awan
you mean like this :

```
 mMap = googleMap;
        if (lati == null) {
            gMap = googleMap;
            center = new LatLng(-7.568737, 110.827062);
            cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(center).zoom(12).build();
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            gMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            gMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
            gMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
            gMap.getUiSettings().setTiltGesturesEnabled(true);


            getLokasi();
        } else {
            gMap = googleMap;
            center = new LatLng(lati, longi);
            cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(center).zoom(12).build();
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            gMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            gMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
            gMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
            gMap.getUiSettings().setTiltGesturesEnabled(true);

            getLokasi();
        }
```